# Asp.net MVC Profile image control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

In my ASP.NET MVC site, the users need to upload profile pictures, and resize/crop and move the image until the user is satisfied (within the red border as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYLom.jpg)

I've stumbled upon the http://imageresizing.net/ which is very fine, but i kinda need the front UI control for the users to use.

What is the easiest way to achieve this kinda control? do i have to develop my own, or do you guys have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, I added 2 links dealing with image re-sizing:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/481015/Rename-Resize-Upload-Image-ASP-NET-MVC
2. http://www.leniel.net/2012/04/resize-img-on-fly-aspnet-webimage.html

I hope it helps, please let me know...

**Update**:
This link may help too (from comments) -

http://techslides.com/image-zoom-drag-and-crop-with-html5

Comment: Not really, what i need is the UI control, where the user can drag and resize the image and make it fit inside the red border, hope that made sense! :-)